# Merge dataframes with unhashable columns

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I want to merge two Pandas DataFrames that are like this:

df1:

```
    lkey       value
0   '200'      1
1   '100'      2
2   '100,300'  3
3   '300'      4
```

df2:

```
    rkey       value
0   '200'      x
1   '100'      y
```

I want to merge them by lkey and rkey:

```
    lkey       rkey   value_l  value_r
0   '200'      '200'        1        x
1   '100'      '100'        2        y
2   '100,300'  '100'        3        y
3   '300'      NaN          4      Nan
```

I tried to do it leaving lkey and rkey as str but it not recognize the intern elements. I mean:

`'100,300' as part of '100'`

this makes sense but I don't know how to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: What should be the result if the key is `'100,200'` instead of `'100,300'` ?

Comment: Are the `'`s actually there, ie. is for example `'200'` the string `"'200'"` or is it just the string `"200"`? If you're not sure then look at the result of `print(df1.applymap(repr))`.

Comment: Or, as the title of your question suggests, are the items in `lkey` (at least partly) actually lists? The best would be to add the result of `print(df1["lkey"].map(repr))` and `print(df2["rkey"].map(repr))` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `merge()` function in Pandas. Since the column names are different, you need to specify the `left_on` and `right_on` parameters to indicate which columns should be used for merging. Additionally, you can use the suffixes parameter to differentiate the columns with the same name in the merged DataFrame. Here's how you can do it:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Assuming df1 and df2 are the input DataFrames

merged_df = df1.merge(df2, left_on='lkey', right_on='rkey', how='left', suffixes=('_l', '_r'))
```

Let me know how it goes!